# Special symbols on HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas, ascii

I want to draw special ASCII symbols on my HTML5 canvas i.e. `&pound;` but they actually show up as the letters themselves rather than a pound symbol.  What can I do to make these show up correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&pound;` is a HTML entity, it doesn't mean anything apart in XML/SGML based markup languages.

But you don't need it as Javascript lets you manage Unicode. Simply use the literal

```
var pound = '£';
```

and be sure to save and serve your javascript files as UTF-8.

Or if you can't use UTF-8, escape it as

```
var pound = "\u00A3";
```

Comment: A side note : HTML lets you use UTF-8 too, so that you don't really have reasons to use &pound; at all (if you have the proper headers and server settings).